# Using smaller picture than PictureBox contol size

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have a `PictureBox` with it's `Dock` set to `Fill`. I want to load pictures that are smaller than the `PictureBox` size. I don't want them to get stretched, is there a way to achive this? I have the `SizeMode` set to `None` but this doesnt help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`PictureBox.SizeMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode.aspx) does not have the property `None`. When you set it to `Normal` or `CenterImage` your image shouldn't be altered within its size.

Answer (score 1):

Use `PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize` which makes  PictureBox sized equal to the size of the image that it contains.

To get more information about `PictureBoxSizeMode` , you can have good tutorial over [here](http://www.functionx.com/vcsharp/controls/picturebox.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set `SizeMode` to `CenterImage`? I think that would solve it.